# Thymeleaf Spring Property or field '' cannot be found on null

Tags: spring, angular, thymeleaf

I am working on a project with Thymeleaf, Spring and Angular. I have a span in my html file which is as follows:

```
<span ng-if="isFurious == '1'" th:text="#{furious-message(${furious_bdate}, ${furious.edate)}" style="color:red;font-weight:bold;"></span>
```

And the relevent message property as follows:

```
furious-message=Object was from {0} till {1} in furious
```

I get the following error when page is loaded

```
**Whitelabel Error Page**

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.


There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "document.begin_date" (units:205)
```

In my Java console I have the following error:

```
Property or field 'bdate' cannot be found on null
```

'bdate' and 'edate' are coming from angular controller.

Kindly let me know if what am I doing wrong.

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: Any help please?

Comment: the angular controller is client side; thymeleaf is a server-side templating engine. you should provide all thymeleaf needs from the server controller (from the java code)

Comment: Ok I understand. To this conbination is not possible. Thanks. I will try an alternative way